# Making an asynchronous AJAX call from within Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to make an asynchronous jquery/ajax call from within a View in Laravel. There is a background worker task that is processed by Redis Queue which is then in turn stored in key:value form on Redis.

Let's say the view is:

***project > app > views > main > search.blade.php***

The script that accesses this key:value pair is in:

***project > app > views > main > getVal.blade.php***

I'm calling *getVal.blade.php* asynchronously through *search.blade.php* :

```
<script>
    var userID = {{ isset($userID)?$userID:'0' }};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'main/getVal',
        data: { id: userId }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( msg );
    });
</script>
```

In routes.php, I have defined *getVal* as:

```
Route::get('main/getVal',function() {
    return View::make('main.search');
});
```

I'm not seeing the *alert box*. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `'main/getVal'` route is defined in the routes.php file to respond to GET requests, but your jQuery is performing an AJAX POST request.  Check your network tab, I imagine you're getting a 404 error from Laravel.  You can also add a `.fail()` function chained to the end:

```
var userID = {{ isset($userID)?$userID:'0' }};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'main/getVal',
    data: { id: userID }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( msg );
}).fail(function() {
    alert('failed!');
});
```

The solution? Make an AJAX GET request instead:

```
var userID = {{ isset($userID)?$userID:'0' }};
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'main/getVal',
    data: { id: userID }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( msg );
}).fail(function() {
    alert('failed!');
});
```

Or, change your route in Laravel to respond to POST requests:

```
Route::post('main/getVal',function() {
    return View::make('main.search');
});
```

Comment: Thanks watcher! the *.fail()* tip helped and of course, I totally missed the route which was defined as a GET instead of a POST! */slaps forehead*

Answer (score 3):

I found the following:

- There is a typo (userID vs userId) which causes an error
- url: 'main/getVal' is a relative address, in Laravel I would use this so it works on any page:
  url: '{{ url('main/getVal')}}'
- As noted by **watcher**, you need to handle the POST request

The complete code that works for me:

```html
# routes.php

Route::get('main/getVal',function() {
    return view('main.search');
});

Route::post('main/getVal',function() {
    return 'This is a test';
});

# search.blade.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var userID = {{ isset($userID)?$userID:'0' }};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ url('main/getVal')}}",
        data: { id: userID }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( msg );
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious typo and for the the *url()* suggestion!